# already installed gems not detected in gem list

Tags: ruby, rubygems, bundler

I ran railsinstaller on a new computer that I bought and afterwards, in an effort to have this computer run all my old rails projects, I copied over all the gem dependencies.  However, for some reason, "bundle install --local" does not work, which is odd since this particular way of copying rails projects and gems worked just fine in the past.  I ran "gem env" and got this:

```
C:\Users\Owner\rails_projects\depot>gem env
RubyGems Environment:
- RUBYGEMS VERSION: 1.8.28
- RUBY VERSION: 1.9.3 (2013-11-22 patchlevel 484) [i386-mingw32]
- INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1
- RUBY EXECUTABLE: C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/bin/ruby.exe
- EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/bin
- RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
  - ruby
  - x86-mingw32
- GEM PATHS:
   - C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1
   - C:/Users/Owner/.gem/ruby/1.9.1
- GEM CONFIGURATION:
   - :update_sources => true
   - :verbose => true
   - :benchmark => false
   - :backtrace => false
   - :bulk_threshold => 1000
- REMOTE SOURCES:
   - http://rubygems.org/
```

I tried being more specific and tried "gem install rake-10.2.2 --local" and I get the following error:

```
ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem 'rake-10.2.2' (>= 0) in any repository
```

And finally, I see that less than half of the actual gems that are in C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems show up when running "gem list".  Any help would be appreciate in figuring out how to get my gems detected.  Thank you.

Comment: What's the output of `ruby -v`?

Comment: I get this: ruby 1.9.3p484 (2013-11-22) [-I386-mingw32]

Comment: Does it appear on `gem server` ?

Comment: I should've said that I'm interested in installing the dependencies offline, by means of copying over from other computers, etc.  That said, do you mean if I can install the gem through rubygems.org? If so, then yes. The gem is rake 10.2.2